# The Package did not load correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I installed visual studio 2019, and when I try to create a project, I get the following error message:

If the project is of the WPF type:
[image: error message]

If the project is of the Console type:
[image]
[image]

If the project is Xamarin.Android:
[image]
[image]

Of course I tried to restart the visual studio, restart the computer and more, but it did not help ...

---

EDIT:

I attach the activityLog.xml file - [ActivityLog.xml](https://github.com/erikVM18294/ActivityLog/blob/master/ActivityLog.xml)

Comment: as suggested, open the ActivityLog.xml and look which errors occured

Comment: @magicandre1981 I tried to read it, but I do not understand from the amount of errors written there what I need to do ....

Comment: post the complete XML here, so that we can look at it

Comment: @magicandre1981 I attached it to the post

Comment: @ErikSmith Hi , do you follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/other/wpf) to create the wpf project,and the errors occurs in which step?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Hi, I created a standard wpf project (regardless of xamarin), and when the project was created, the xaml did not work and I received the above error message.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT The same thing happens when I try to work on a xamarin project - a message is displayed that there are packages that have not been loaded correctly.

Comment: it looks like your Visual Studio install is broken. Open VS Installer and repair the VS.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I just did a repair to the visual studio and I still get these errors ...

Comment: post more details about your system (Hardware, used windows 10 build, other installed software)

Comment: @magicandre1981
Hardware - intel core i5-8250u, 8GB RAM, 64bit operating system, x64 based processor,
Windows - Windows 10 Home Version 1903

,I have visual studio 2017 installed and working perfectly fine